# SQL Query required

Tags: sql

I have a table like

```
DEPT   Years   Subject
ECE      1       Maths
ECE      1       PDC
EEE      1       Maths
EEE      1       ET
MEC      1       Maths
MEC      1       ET
```

I want the query to find all DEPT (departments) in which subjects are repeated like Maths in ECE, EEE & MEC and ET repeated in EEE & MEC i.e., only repeated ones

Please advice,

Comment: Can you tell us what concrete database system this is for, and what you have tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table group by Subject having count(dept) > 1;
```

Comment: Column "dbo.test110.DEPT" is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following:**

```
select a.dept,a.Subject from tableName a,b where a.dept=b.dept
```

Comment: This will list all rows because they're each equal to themselves.

Comment: interesting, but PDC should not be in the resultset

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT dept, Subject FROM tableName WHERE Subject IN (SELECT Subject FROM tableName GROUP BY Subject HAVING COUNT(Subject)>1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from tabelname where subject in ( select subject from tablename 
 group by subject having count(subject) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
SELECT DEPT, Subject FROM Table1 WHERE Subject IN 
 (SELECT Subject FROM Table1 GROUP BY Subject HAVING COUNT(Subject)>1);
```

Live example here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5885/12

The output is as follows:

```
DEPT    SUBJECT
ECE         Maths
EEE         Maths
EEE         ET
MEC         Maths
MEC         ET
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE SUBJECT IN 
(SELECT SUBJECT FROM XYZ HAVING COUNT(SUBJECT)>1 
GROUP    BY SUBJECT);
```

HERE IS THE END TABLE

```
DEPT             YEAR SUBJECT
---------- ---------- ----------
EEE                 1 MATHS
EEE                 1 ET
MEC                 1 MATHS
MEC                 1 ET
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    DEPT,
    Subject
FROM tablename
WHERE
     Subject IN (
                SELECT [Subject] FROM (
                                       SELECT [Subject],count([Subject]) AS CountSubj FROM tablename GROUP BY [Subject]
                                      ) AS subtbl
                WHERE subtbl.CountSubj>1)
ORDER BY Subject
```

try above sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Use option with EXISTS operator

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test110 t
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test110 t2
              WHERE t.Subject  = t2.Subject
              HAVING COUNT(t2.Subject) > 1
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/567f7/1)